# Enabling developer mode in Reliance LYF

Tags: developer-options, reliance-lyf

I have a Reliance LYF mobile phone and want to enable the developer mode.

I looked for all options in the settings but haven't found anything to enable developer mode.

Is the developer mode option available on it?

Comment: Was this bought as a used device? The single-use option may have been used by the former owner.

Comment: @wbogacz I am confused. What do you mean by single use option?

Comment: @PN10 I assume that you were stuck on Google FRP lock screen? You can't unlock developer option if the phone is FRP locked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > About device, then tap on "Build number" for 7 times, then go back. The developer option will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

1. This phone is based on Firefox OS, meaning that tapping build number 7 times won't help.
2. The developer portal for Kaios recently became a thing. However, they don't give instructions on how to enable developer mode (yet).

This indicates 2 things:

1. The documentations are incomplete (which they clearly are, most of it is from the Firefox OS documentation),
2. An update for it auto enables developer mode.

Comment: All Lyf smartphones launched as of 2016 run Android operating system. Some Lyf smartphones launched after 2016 also run Android.